# Styling Range slider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a simple Range slider like in this image below:

[image: wanted slider look]

But for now it looks like this:

[image: current slider look]

Here is code, i wrapped RangeSlider in SliderTheme and added custom styling for slider but it still doesn't work it looks like in the second image:

```
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: const SliderThemeData(
                          rangeTrackShape: RectangularRangeSliderTrackShape(),
                          thumbShape: CustomThumbShape()),
                      child: RangeSlider(
                        activeColor: Colors.white,
                        inactiveColor: const Color(0xFFB08246),
                        values: RangeValues(
                            searchCriteria.priceFrom, searchCriteria.priceTo),
                        min: 250.0,
                        max: 200000.0,
                        divisions: 100,
                        labels: RangeLabels(
                          '${searchCriteria.priceFrom.round()}',
                          '${searchCriteria.priceTo.round()}',
                        ),
                        onChanged: (RangeValues values) {
                          updateRangeValues(values, 'price');
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

And here is CustomThumbShape class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  final double thumbRadius;

  const CustomThumbShape({this.thumbRadius = 12.0});

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(thumbRadius);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.transparent
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final Paint outlinePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 2
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    final double thumbRadiusWithOutline = thumbRadius + 2;

    canvas.drawCircle(center, thumbRadiusWithOutline, outlinePaint);

    canvas.drawCircle(center, thumbRadius, paint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The range slider is working only with the active color. If we use Slider() then it'll work as expected. So, for range slider you can use a package: [another_xlider](https://pub.dev/packages/another_xlider)     , In this you can set custom decoration in "handler" and "rightHandler" parameters.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({super.key});

 @override
 State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
 }

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
double _lowerValue = 50;
double _upperValue = 200;

 final handlers = FlutterSliderHandler(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xFF12142B),
      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white),
      shape: BoxShape.circle),
  child: const SizedBox());

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xff12142B),
  body: Center(
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: FlutterSlider(
        trackBar: const FlutterSliderTrackBar(
            activeTrackBar: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white)),
        handler: handlers,
        rightHandler: handlers,
        values: [_lowerValue, _upperValue],
        rangeSlider: true,
        max: 500,
        min: 0,
        onDragging: (handlerIndex, lowerValue, upperValue) {
          _lowerValue = lowerValue;
          _upperValue = upperValue;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```